# Storing values obtained from for each loop Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, foreach

Scala beginner who is trying to store values obtains in a Scala foreach loop but failing miserably.
The basic foreach loop looks like this currently:

```
order.orderList.foreach((x: OrderRef) => {
   val references = x.ref}))
```

When run this foreach loop will execute twice and return a reference each time. I'm trying to capture the reference value it returns on each run (so two references in either a list or array form so I can access these values later)

I'm really confused about how to go about doing this...

I attempted to retrieve and store the values as an array but when ran, the array list doesn't seem to hold any values.

This was my attempt:

```
val newArray = Array(order.orderList.foreach((x: OrderRef) => {
    val references = x.ref
  }))
  println(newArray)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. If there is a better way to achieve this, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `foreach`

```
order.orderList.map((x: OrderRef) => {x.ref}))
```

Also `val references = x.ref` doesn't return anything. It create new local variable and assign value to it.

Comment: Thanks, so I don't need that local variable since the Array will store the results? Also is there a way to store the values from an Array into x number of separate variables? i know i can access them using an index, but I'm looking to future proof it

Comment: You ask "Also is there a way to store the values from an Array into x number of separate variables?" the answer is no. You can only do it one by one in your code.

Comment: If you know the size of the array, and it is fixed, then yes, you can do that:
`val Array(foo, bar, baz) = order.orderList.map(_.x.ref)` (but beware: this only works if `order.orderList` is an `Array` of exactly three elements).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with answer 1, and I believe the reason is below:

Return of 'foreach' or 'for' should be 'Unit', and 'map' is an with an changed type result like example below:

`def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Array[B]`

Compare To `for` and `foreach`, the prototype should be like this

`def foreach(f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit`

So If you wanna to get an changed data which is maped from your source data, considering more about functions like `map`, `flatMap`, and these functions will traverse all datas like `for` and `foreach`(except with `yield`), but with return values.